# Why do some upvote events increment reputation differently?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

If you look at [Martijn Pieters's reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation), profile, you'll notice that yesterday he earned 208 reputation.  That's really confusing, because the rep cap is 200.

I see a few upvotes gave him 3 points, some gave him 2, and several gave him 1.  There was a downvote, so it all adds up like this: `3 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 - 2 = 8` — so I see where the 8 in 208 is coming from, but...why?

Comment: An overclairification of Ryan's answer: If you [sort by time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation&sort=time) and read [the list bottom to top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aurgS.jpg) he got cut off at 200. Then he lost some rep, either by someone DVing or his own DVs on answers, that enabled additional UVs to give him: 1 (for his answer DV), 2 (someone DVed him), or 3 (possibly 3 of his DVs or 1 of his and someone else's DV (whose indication is delayed, and *invisible*)). That shows 8 that weren't *counteracted*, providing 208; 200 of which he keeps, 8 lost.

Comment: @gnat that doesn't really, because I understand all the events that can change rep.  In this case, I was asking specifically for an explanation of some very non-obvious changes that I could not understand.  Ryan's answer below and Rob's comment above have helped a lot.  The question you linked doesn't help me understand the occurence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word: downvotes.  Both by Martijn and on his posts.  Downvoting answers costs 1 rep, and one of your posts being downvoted costs 2 rep.  However, voting is secret, so the reputation lost for downvoting answers is only shown to you, not to other people viewing your profile.

If we look at Martijn's [activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=topactivity), we see that he has cast 8 votes this month, and isn't shy about downvoting:

[image: Votes cast: 5825 up, 21846 down, 18461 on questions, 9210 on answers, 8 this month, 8 this week]

From the reputation history for yesterday, we also see that he received one downvote:
[image: 1 downvote for -2 reputation]

The upvotes that weren't worth +10 all add up to +10, which lines up with the 8 rep lost for the 8 votes cast (since they were all downvotes on answers, apparently) plus the 2 rep lost for the one downvote on Martijn's post.  The next upvote after each of these events gives just enough rep to bring him back up to +200 for the day.

[image: 6 upvotes, worth, in order from top to bottom: +3, +2, +2, +1, +1, +1]

Comment: Though Martijn _also_ received two +1 upvotes on Aug 1...so it sure looks like two answer downvotes got lost in the monthly vote tracking...

Comment: The vote tracking can get muddled by caching and batch processes handling rep invalidations for deleted posts as well. As a moderator I come across a lot of downvote-worthy content plus we use downvotes as a tool in very specific cases (forcing rep invalidation on a plagiarised post with score 3 is one such case).  So my rep history can be quite messy. But, it still all tallies up correctly!